# Difference between using a list or a pcollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

Im building a pipeline in apache beam and I just got curious about this, whats the difference between applying a ptransform to a list and a pcollection, is the performance affected by this or is just that the pcollection is inmutable and is this a bad way to aproach a pipeline with apache beam?

Comment: Do you mean to say PCollectionList<T>? If so, could you please specify the exact kind of transform you're thinking of applying.

Comment: I created a list numbers=[1,2,3,4,5] and then used it like numbers | beam.ParDo(odd_numbers())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a PCollection is a unbounded collection. Immutable, and **unbounded**.

The main difference with a list is mainly the unbounded characteristic and it's especially powerful when you are streaming data (from a large file, or from a unbounded source, like PubSub).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should I avoid using ptransforms on lists and others that are not a pcollection or are there use cases where this could be a desire way to proceed?

Comment: You can use a ptransform on a list, why not! For instance, you can use the same transform on a PCollection and on a list to normalize them and be able to merge them afterward.